# ajax responsetext different variables

Tags: php, ajax, variables, responsetext

I have ajax function validating username. It says OK if it's ok and some red text if there is a problem using

```
document.getElementById("username_status").innerHTML = return_data;
```

But If I want to have for example two divs, one with id username_status and another with I don't know, just id error. And I want to put different things in them. So in php I won't make echo sth, but I'll create some variables like message = username is fine. and error = some error. And I want to put text in message variable to div with id username_status, and error variable to div with id error. How to make this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to return an array.

Create your response in php as an array.

Then use JSON enconde and decode.

Then manage your array in JAVASCRIPT.

In the first position you can put the result, in the second the error ID if any, whatever you want.. and handle it in the JS.

Assuming you are using PHP (but you can encode in JSON from any languages)

HERE IS YOUR CODE

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#prev').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: 'id=testdata',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    $('#content1').html(result[0]);
  },
  });
});
});
```